# can ' what is' be shortened in 'what is it'?

Tags: usage, contractions

> > What's it?
>
> should be 'What is it?' we don't shorten "what is" in a case like
> this. only if it is not followed by a continuing phrase.

Is the claim from a chat with a stranger true?

What's a continuing phrase?

Comment: Here: "What's it to ya, huh?," "What's it all about, Alfie?," or "What's it like in Glocca Morra?"

Comment: There is a UK cheese flavoured corn snack called [Wotsits](https://www.walkers.co.uk/our-range/family-snacks/wotsits-cheese).

Comment: Yes, it's true.. We don't use: What's it. unless by that you mean what does it refer to/

Comment: @Lambie what's "unless by that you mean what does it refer to/"?

Comment: @Tim I think they mean if you're asking about the word "it". As you can see there are edge cases, but in general "what is it" can't be shortened this way.

Comment: We can say "What's _that_?" (pointing to something) but not "What's it?" _It_ usually refers to something already mentioned, so we would emphasise the verb - "What _is_ it?" (The name of @MichaelHarvey's 'Wotsits' is from the noun _whatsit_, one of those words for something you can't remember the name of.)

Comment: It's not standard, but I think it may be used in some dialects.

Comment: @YosefBaskin the contraction "what's" does not appear in the song _How are things in Glocca Morra?_

Comment: @phoog That is correct. It was a form of humor to make a point using part of a familiar phrasing.

Answer (score 1):

The statement is true, in my estimation.

One might say, "What's it mean?" or "What's it's name?" to a question about a word, or a pet's name. I.E., the phrase is not used in isolation.

Other than as almost meaningless [discourse marker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discourse_marker), "What's it?" is not used. Perhaps when someone is concentrating on a task, and repeatedly is interrupted, a loud "What's it?" might be appropriate... certainly moreso than an expletive.